# Ionic facebook login ngopenfb not working in android 5.1

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I am using `ngopenfb` for facebook login in my ionic hybrid mobile app.

When I click facebook signin a blank white screen appears.

This issue is happening in android 5.*, for android 4.* facebook login page appears.

Kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: use the official facebook plugin for cordova https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin